# Contraction of square tensors

Tags: matrix, tensors

Let there be tensors A and B

```
A = Outer[Times, {1, 0}, {2, 0}]
B = Grad[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, y}]
```

with output

```
{{2, 0}, {0, 0}}
{{(f^(1,0))[x,y],(f^(0,1))[x,y]},{(g^(1,0))[x,y],(g^(0,1))[x,y]}}
```

Now, I am looking for tensor contraction of A and B ($A:B$) as follows

```
TensorContract[A, B]
```

Which produces output

```
TensorContract::contr: Invalid contraction {(f^(1,0))[x,y],(f^(0,1))[x,y]}.
```

How can get the correct result, in this case $2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$?

Comment: `Total[A B,2]` or `TensorContract[TensorProduct[A, B], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]`.

Comment: Thanks @HenrikSchumacher, If you can post it as an answer, I can accept it. In the second solution what does weird order of indices {{1,3},{2,4}} stands for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest method for matrices:

```
Total[A B, 2]
```

One can also use a Frobenius innerproduct

```
Tr[Transpose[A].B]
```

or simply

```
Flatten[A].Flatten[B]
```

In fact, the last one should be the most efficient for large numerical matrices (it takes advantage of vectorization and fused multiply-add operations).

If one insists on using `TensorContract`, one has to generate a tensor $A \otimes B$ first and then contract the slot pairs `{1, 3}` and `{2, 4}`

```
TensorContract[TensorProduct[A, B], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]
```

This is however not a good idea, because the intermediate tensor $A \otimes B$ contains $n^4$ elements when $A$ and $B$ are both $n \times n$ matrices.

By the way, `Tr[Transpose[A].B]` is also of complexity $O(n^3)$ due to the matrix-matrix product; so better also avoid that one.

Comment: Using `Activate@TensorContract[Inactive[TensorProduct][A, B], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]` helps alleviate the intermediate swell, although it still won't be as fast as the other methods.

Comment: @CarlWoll Ah, that's good to know! Thank you.